# Get value of keys in object in array?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I am someone who has been trying out webdesign for around 2 months now and I have a question. So I have the following array with object:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Post)#416 (24) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(36)
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(7) "Bakuman"
}
```

I am trying to get the value of "ID", but am not sure how to go about referencing it.
I have tried `[0]["ID"]`, but doesn't work.

**Also:** Is it possible to get the ID without mentioning the #416 number?

Tried searching for answer, but keep coming up with results that have large amounts of OOP with so much info I can't filter through to what I need. Can anyone hlpe me out?

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses `->` for object properties.

So in your case

```
echo $array[0]->ID;
```

should output `36`

where `[0]` is the first element of `$array` which contains the `WP_Post` object and `ID` is the property containing the value you're looking for

Comment: @downvoter care to provide some constructive feedback by leaving a comment? or are you just going with hitting the -1 button?

Answer (score 1):

The 0th element of your array is in fact an object, so to access its properties, you need to use the object referencing operator `->`.

Try this: `$array[0]->ID`